# GUI application works fine, when jar started over console but bug if jar started by doubleclicking

Tags: java

I have a GUI application and it works fine, when started over the console. If I start the jar by doubleclicking, it starts fine, but at some point, probably, when reading a serialized object from the jar, it stops.

The relevant code:

```
public static void nashEQ() {
    if(!running){
    running = true;
    Generator.generateTables();
    int u0 = Generator.handRanks[53 + Board[0]];
    int u1 = Generator.handRanks[u0 + Board[1]];
    int u2 = Generator.handRanks[u1 + Board[2]];
    int u3 = Generator.handRanks[u2 + Board[3]];
    int u4 = Generator.handRanks[u3 + Board[4]];
    distributionOne.setProbabilities();
    distributionTwo.setProbabilities();
    distributionOne.SetRelativeProbabilities(distributionTwo);
    distributionTwo.SetRelativeProbabilities(distributionOne);
    distributionOne.setRanks(u4);
    distributionTwo.setRanks(u4);
    DecisionNode d = createGame();
    double[] p1 = distributionOne.getProbabilities();
    double[] p2 = distributionTwo.getProbabilities();
    for (int i = 0; i <= MaxIteration; i++) {
        d.trainVanilla(0, p1, p2);
        d.trainVanilla(1, p2, p1);
        CurrentIteration = i;
    }
    // double br0 = d.bestResponse(0);
    // double br1 = d.bestResponse(1);
    // System.out.println("BR0: " + br0);
    // System.out.println("BR1: " + br1);
    // System.out.println("Exploitability: " + Math.abs(pot - (br0 + br1)));
    double[] r = d.trainVanilla(0, p1, p2);
    double res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        res += 1.0 / r.length * r[i];
    }
    System.out.println("EV: " + res);
    Save save = Save.createSave(d);
    SimpleViewerDialog saveD = new SimpleViewerDialog(save);
    saveD.setVisible(true);
    running = false;
}
}
public static void generateTables() {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object o = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(Generator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("handEvaluation/handRanks"));
        o = ois.readObject();
        if (o instanceof int[]) {
            handRanks = (int[]) o;
        }
    }catch(EOFException e){
        if (o instanceof int[]) {
            handRanks = (int[]) o;
        }
    }       
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        int card;
        int handRank;
        int keyIndex;
        long key;
        for (keyIndex = 0; keys[keyIndex] != 0 || keyIndex == 0; keyIndex++) {

            for (card = 1; card < 53; card++) { // add a card to each
                                                // previously calculated key
                key = makeKey(keys[keyIndex], card); // create the new key

                if (numCards < 7)
                    insertKey(key); // insert the new key into the key
                                    // lookup table
            }
        }
        for (keyIndex = 0; keys[keyIndex] != 0 || keyIndex == 0; keyIndex++) {

            for (card = 1; card < 53; card++) {
                key = makeKey(keys[keyIndex], card);

                if (numCards < 7) {
                    handRank = insertKey(key) * 53 + 53; // if number of
                                                            // cards is < 7
                                                            // insert key
                } else {
                    handRank = getHandRank(key); // if number of cards is 7
                                                    // insert hand rank
                }

                maxHandRankIndex = keyIndex * 53 + card + 53; // calculate
                                                                // hand rank
                                                                // insertion
                                                                // index
                handRanks[maxHandRankIndex] = handRank; // populate hand
                                                        // rank lookup table
                                                        // with appropriate
                                                        // value
            }

            if (numCards == 6 || numCards == 7) {
                // insert the hand rank into the hand rank lookup table
                handRanks[keyIndex * 53 + 53] = getHandRank(keys[keyIndex]);
            }
        }
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                    "src/handEvaluation/handRanks"));
            oos.writeObject(handRanks);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            f.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            f.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null)
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException g) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    } finally {
        if (ois != null)
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException g) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                g.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
} // END generateTables method
```

Comment: When you say it stops, you do get a stacktrace, right? Could you post that one?

Comment: This `"src/handEvaluation/handRanks"` seems wrong to me.  It is unlikely that you will have access to the `src` directory at run time.  The likely cause is that the programs execution context (the directory from which it is running) is different between the console and that when you double click it...

Comment: I dont get any console output or stacktrace, when I open the jar by double clicking, even if I open a console beforehand.

Comment: The part, where I use src/.... doesnt get executed. It only gets executed, if the handRanks file wasnt created yet, so it shouldnt be a problem. I checked the path when I open it via console and doubleclick and its both file:/C:/CFRM.jar!/handEvaluation/handRanks.

Comment: Have you tried to start it from within a console (`java...`) rather than double clicking it?

Comment: @reto  *"Have you tried to start it from within a console.."* See the *first sentence* of the question.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: @reto  (shrugs) I've done much the same thing - many times.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:
The reason for the error was, that the JVM allocated more memory, when I started it over the console, than with a doubleclick, even though I didn't pass any parameters over the console.

I had an OutOfMemoryException. I fixed it by increasing the heapsize.